# Parse XML string stored on Oracle Table

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I've a XML string like that stored on my DB:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AddressMaintenance>
<Label Name="lblAddress11">Address Line 1</Label><TextBox Name="txtAddress11">Zuellig Korea</TextBox>
</AddressMaintenance>
```

do you know if there is a way to extract the value **Zuelling Korea** using XMLQuery or SQL? I can't create a temporary table because it's a validate environment so I can only read that value. I know is possible using reg exp, but, if possible I try to use XML.

thanks,
Andrea

Comment: +1, looking for exactly the same thing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is stored in an XMLTYPE on a table you can use the Oracle XML functions to extract it using XPath:

```
SELECT
  extractvalue(xmlcol, '/*/TextBox[@Name=''txtAddress11'']') txtaddress
FROM yourtable
```

Adapt the XPath to suit your needs.

See [ExtractValue documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions052.htm) or research other Oracle XML functions.

---

I should probably note that 11g and later, extractvalue is deprecated and you should use [XMLQuery](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions224.htm)

Comment: I think xmlcol need to be an Xml datatype because when I try to execute the SQL Query it returns ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got -

Comment: Ah sorry I was under the impression the column was XMLTYPE. If you've got a VARCHAR2 / string you can use the XMLTYPE() function. So your query becomes SELECT extractvalue(xmltype(xmlcol), 'xpath') FROM yourtable