# Oracle XML select results into a table

Tags: xml, oracle11g, xquery

if I have a XML column which elements have the following structure

> ```
> > <library>
> >     <bookshelf>
> >         <book>
> >         <book>
> >           ...
> >         <book>
> >     </bookshelf> </library>
> ```

How can I retrieve all the information and put it into a table which columns look like this
LIBRARY BOOKSHELF BOOK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715696/parse-xml-string-stored-on-oracle-table) question might help you with extracting each column wise and inserting.