# ORACLE Parsing XML string into separate records

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I'm trying to find members of several groups. The group membership is stored as XML in an ORACLE database. I need a SQL query to split each member into a separate rows.

I've seen a few posts on using xmlsequence without success through lack of understanding.

A sample string is

```
<D:href xmlns:D='DAV:'>/users/admin@Native Directory</D:href>
<D:href xmlns:D='DAV:'>/users/oracle@Native Directory</D:href>
<D:href xmlns:D='DAV:'>/users/user1@DomainProd</D:href>
```

My current results are

```
Group       User
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
group1      <D:href xmlns:D='DAV:'>/users/admin@Native Directory</D:href>
            <D:href xmlns:D='DAV:'>/users/oracle@Native Directory</D:href>
            <D:href xmlns:D='DAV:'>/users/user1@DomainProd</D:href>
group2      <D:href xmlns:D='DAV:'>/users/admin@Native Directory</D:href>
            <D:href xmlns:D='DAV:'>/users/oracle@Native Directory</D:href>
            <D:href xmlns:D='DAV:'>/users/user1@DomainProd</D:href>
group3      <D:href xmlns:D='DAV:'>/users/admin@Native Directory</D:href>
            <D:href xmlns:D='DAV:'>/users/oracle@Native Directory</D:href>
            <D:href xmlns:D='DAV:'>/users/user1@DomainProd</D:href>
```

I want my results set to be

```
Group       User
-------------------
group1      admin
group1      oracle
group1      user1
group2      admin
group2      oracle
group2      user1
group3      admin
group3      oracle
group3      user1
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715696/parse-xml-string-stored-on-oracle-table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use XMLTABLE. as your XML document seems to be a fragment in the row, i've wrapped this in a `<root>` element.

```
select grp, substr(name, 
              instr(name, '/', -1) + 1,
              instr(name, '@') - instr(name, '/', -1) - 1
             ) name
  from mytab m, 
       xmltable(xmlnamespaces('DAV:' as "D"), 
                '/root/D:href' passing xmltype('<root>'||usr||'</root>')
                columns
                name varchar2(200) path './text()');
```

i've assumed a table where your xml column is stored as a clob/varchar2 called (usr) .

example output for group1:

```
SQL> select grp, substr(name,
  2                instr(name, '/', -1) + 1,
  3                instr(name, '@') - instr(name, '/', -1) - 1
  4               ) name
  5    from mytab m,
  6         xmltable(xmlnamespaces('DAV:' as "D"),
  7                  '/root/D:href' passing xmltype('<root>'||usr||'</root>')
  8                  COLUMNS
  9                  name VARCHAR2(200) path './text()');

GRP    NAME
------ ----------
group1 admin
group1 oracle
group1 user1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/435cd/1

Comment: Thanks @DazzaL. It's working on sqlfiddle but not on the server. I'm getting **ORA-19102: XQuery string literal expected.** The query i'm using it `select X.name
  from PROPERTIES p,
    xmltable(xmlnamespaces('DAV:' as "D"),
    '/root/D:href' passing xmltype('<root>'||p.PROPERTY_VALUE||'</root>')
                COLUMNS
                name CLOB PATH './text()') X'`

Comment: @5hak3y this may be because you have CURSOR_SHARING set to FORCE or SIMILAR. can you confirm this? a simple way of seeing is add this hint in `select /*+ cursor_sharing_exact */ grp`

Answer (score 0):

[@DazzaL's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14416569/1083652) is a good one (and probably faster in most cases),
but you can also do something like this:

```
with tt as 
(select ggroup, regexp_replace(uuser, '([[:print:]]*)(/users/)([[:alnum:]]*)(@)([[:print:]]*)','\3,') user_csv
from t)
select distinct ggroup, regexp_substr(user_csv,'[^,]+',1,level)
from tt
connect by regexp_substr(user_csv,'[^,]+',1,level) is not null
order by ggroup
```

`t` in my query is the table's name

[**Here is a sqlfiddle demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/40c8c/1)